# How to export .dae(collada) contain bone animation for three.js?

Tags: three.js, blender

I have created a simple cube animation in blender (which goes up and down) and i am exporting it to .dae file. I need to import that collada file in three.js but animation is not working. I have gone through .dae file and i found that `<library_animation_clips>` tag is missing but in three.js sample monster.dae file contains that tag.

can any one give steps how to export .dae animation file in blender for three.js?

Comment: library_animation_clip tag is missing sorry for not mentioning tag name

Comment: Blenders collada exporter is very bad. I suggest using the three js blender exporter to export animated meshes.

Comment: how to install that three.js addon i have placed io_three addon to addons folder but it wont show in export option

Comment: press ctrl-alt-U for user preferences then enable it under the add-ons tab.